# Play 2 - Call b/w 2 controller methods does not invoke actions

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Am using play 2.2.3 version. I have 2 controllers and when am trying to invoke a method (with action composition) from one controller to other, the action class is not being called.

Controller1.java
 
    `@CustomAction(actionName="myAction")
    public static Result getData()
    {
         System.out.println("From Controller 1");
         return ok("From Controller 1");
    }`

Controller2.java
 
    `public static Result index()
    {
         System.out.println("From Controller 2");
         Result result = Controller1.getData();
         String s =new String(JavaResultExtractor.getBody((SimpleResult) result));
         return ok(index.render(s));
    }`

routes

  `GET     /view                       controllers.Controller2.index()
  GET     /getData                    controllers.Controller1.getData()`

when i invoke `http://localhost:9000/getData`, the action class is being invoked successfully.

But when i invoke `http://localhost:9000/view` , the action class is not being invoked.

Am not sure what is the right approach to invoke a controller method from another controller. 
Any help on this would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By calling `Controller1.getData()` directly you are bypassing any request processing done by Play. I.e. you are just calling a static method on a Java class, outside the context of Play code.

It's not clear what you're ultimately trying to accomplish from your example code, so can only advise that you either:

- add `@CustomAction` to `Controller2.index()` if applicable
- strip out common functionality into another class and let both controllers invoke that class (should not return `Result`)
- or, if applicable, redirect to `Controller1.getData()` from `Controller2.index()` (e.g: `return redirect(routes.Controller1.getData());`)

Comment: Thank u for reply Donovan. As u said i will brief the use case so that the problem statement might me clear.

Comment: One of the use case. - Suppose i have a authorization annotation something like `@Restrict(@Group("admin"))` on the `getData` method of `Controller1`, then the condition would not be evaluated if i invoke the `getData` method from Controller2. Hope am clear with the use case.

Comment: Is there any reason you could not then add `@Restrict(@Group("admin"))` to `Controller2.index()` as well?

Comment: Right Donovan. I can have the `@Restrict(@Group("admin"))` on Controller2 as well but with a different role, say `@Restrict(@Group("role3"))`. i.e. 'getData` has `@Restrict(@Group("admin"))` and `index` has @Restrict(@Group("role3")).So in this use case the authorization will not be evaluated. Also as i mentioned this is one of the use case.